# Multiple encryption of part of block

Tags: encryption, block-cipher, multiple-encryption, blocksize

Is there any security risk in encrypting parts of blocks twice? I'd like to get around block sizes and make encrypted messages just as long as the unencrypted ones:

> **Block 1**: Byte 0 - 7
> **Block 2**: Byte 8 - 15
> **Block 3**: Byte 16 - 23
> **Block 4**: Byte **21** - 29

In this example blocks 3 and 4 overlap by 2 bytes. I plan on using CAST-128.

Thank you very much for helping!

Florian

Comment: ... with what [mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation)? $\;$

Comment: We want to use ECB

Comment: Do you understand the risks of using ECB? Also, do you understand the risks of using a block cipher that has a 64-bit block?

Comment: We could use CBC. We went for 64-bit blocks because of the small message in an effort to not produce overhead. would it be better to use overlapping 128-bit blocks?

Comment: 1) This technique is known as [Ciphertext stealing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ciphertext_stealing). It's secure in principle, but as @mikeazo already pointed out using ECB and using 64 bit block ciphers is generally a bad idea. 2) There are fancier [length preserving encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format-preserving_encryption) schemes. 3) I strongly recommend adding a nonce/IV and a MAC. While these increase the size of the message, the security implications of not having them can be severe.

Comment: I don't see the reason in your proposal. It doesn't look like ciphertext stealing, and I don't see any way how that would help in the case that encrypted messages are as long as the plaintext messages - you still need the whole output of the cipher if you want to decrypt the message. And you still have to know which part of the message was original and which was repeated.

Comment: @Nova How is it not ciphertext stealing?

Comment: @CodesInChaos: This scheme "steals" input data, not ciphertext. The bytes 21, 22 and 23 are just two times encrypted, and without additional data it is impossible to know which ones were two times encrypted.

Comment: @Nova The description is a bit unclear, but I assumed that Block 4 uses the first few bytes from the ciphertext not from the plaintext, since else the whole scheme wouldn't make sense.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: Yeah, I also assumed that, but I can't be sure if Florian did know that. Not everyone does know this.

Comment: @Nova It has been implemented the way CodesInChaos described it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This technique is known as [Ciphertext stealing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ciphertext_stealing). Ciphertext stealing avoids padding, but only works if the total message size is bigger than one block.

   Ciphertext stealing secure in principle, but as @mikeazo already pointed out using ECB and using 64 bit block ciphers is generally a bad idea.
2. There are fancier [length preserving encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format-preserving_encryption) schemes. FFX mode is one example.
3. I strongly recommend adding a nonce/IV and a MAC. While these increase the size of the message, the security implications of not having them can be severe.

   In particular the MAC prevents attacks that modify the ciphertext and watch the reaction of the decrypted and nonces/IVs ensure that encrypting the message twice doesn't leak that it's the same.

Answer (score 0):

with CAST-128 your getting the same length output as input anyway. byte 23 and 21 don't overlap there. your just putting the input to that function with the key and it should return an array of bytes that is of the same length as the input. you should not have to worry about those bytes overlapping.

Comment: With certain modes, the plaintext must be padded, so then the output would be larger.